# Xamarin convert rawValue

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.mac

I am trying to underline the title for NSButton in Xamarin.MacOS.
In the mutable attributed string, I use

```
attrString.AddAttribute(NSStringAttributeKey.UnderlineStyle, NSNumber.FromInt32((int)NSUnderlineStyle.Single), range);
```

It doesn't work.  Suggestions in Swift is to use

```
let underlineAttribute = [NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue]
```

In Xamarin.MacOS, there is no NSUnderlineStyle.Single.RawValue.  How do I get the RawValue of NSUnderlineStyle enum?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am adding underline like this:

```
str.AddAttribute(NSStringAttributeKey.UnderlineStyle, new NSNumber((int)NSUnderlineStyle.Single), new NSRange(0, str.Length));
```

I can confirm this works in both `NSTextView` and `NSButton`

Answer (score 0):

First, a quick review. `NSUnderlineStyle` is an enumeration with the following values:

```
NSUnderlineStyleNone = 0x00,
NSUnderlineStyleSingle = 0x01,
NSUnderlineStyleThick = 0x02,
NSUnderlineStyleDouble = 0x09,
NSUnderlinePatternSolid = 0x0000,

NSUnderlinePatternDot = 0x0100,
NSUnderlinePatternDash = 0x0200,
NSUnderlinePatternDashDot = 0x0300,
NSUnderlinePatternDashDotDot = 0x0400,

NSUnderlineByWord = 0x8000
```

So we could check the following code

```
string prefixedHex = "0x01";
            
int intValue = Convert.ToInt32(prefixedHex, 16);

NSMutableAttributedString str = new NSMutableAttributedString();
      str.AddAttribute(NSStringAttributeKey.UnderlineStyle,NSNumber.FromInt32(1),range);

button.AttributedTitle = str;
```

Comment: I have tried it - NSNumber.FromInt32(1) - but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the original code.

```
attrString.AddAttribute(NSStringAttributeKey.UnderlineStyle, NSNumber.FromInt32((int)NSUnderlineStyle.Single), range);
```

I have forgotten to set this attribute in the OnElementPropertyChanged function.
Thanks for your confirmation that it works which prompts me to re-investigate my code. I spent a few days debugging it thinking that the issue is with rawValue.